# Classifying type samples from image files

Tags: image, machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

Which approach would you suggest for automatically classifying type found in images? The samples are likely large, with black text on a white background.

The categories are defined here, with some examples on each (Google Books link): http://bit.ly/9Mnu7P This is an extended version of the VOX-ATypI classification system.

My initial thoughts on this were to train the system with lots of single character samples from each category, but I'm wondering if there's a better way that would eliminate the need to do the comparison one letter at a time.

Comment: Tagging it with "computer-vision" might be useful.

Comment: Tagged. I'd also like to add that I'm trying to avoid resorting to really expensive solutions, no matter how good they are. This one does look promising, though: http://www.ideeinc.com/products/piximilar/

Comment: Well, you can try it. But general solutions are often ineffective or inefficient. I believe you need to implement a specific method. For example, they seem to use color saturation as a feature, which is totally useless in your case.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to extract features for classification. Typefaces are generally distinguished by the thickness of lines, the presence of serifs, "circularity" of character parts. Thus, the possible features are:

- The fraction of the number of black pixels on the fixed area.
- Try to apply math morphology [erosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Erosion) few times (and/or use different masks) and compute this fraction
- Compute the mean compactness of a character: perimeter^2 / area
- After applying erosion, count the number of connected components for a character
- Compute the elongation and other [image moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment), also the direction
- etc

I see two options here: either compute mean features for all characters, or try to classify letters first, and than classify the font based on some specific letters (so, you train the different classifier for a different letter). It's hard to say which one is better in your case.

As for specific learning algorithm, [Random Forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) seems to be a good place to start. There's an implementation in the [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) library.